# Unity 3d Interactive Book Design

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm designing an interactive book using Unity 3d.
I've some ideas of how to do this but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.
This interactive book contains around 15 pages, in which 12 of those pages contain apart from text, some animations that the user can trigger.
There are also sound effects (e.g. storm sounds, birds singing, etc) and a background soundtrack. It's very likely that a narrator voice would be present during the reading of the text, because it's intended to be an accessible application.(e.g. blind people could not read so they have to listen).
I've been thinking in the following design:

Create one scene per page. The idea is to represent each page through a scene, so we will have around 15 scenes.
Each scene will contain sound effects, audio tracks, narrator voice, text of the book and animations that can be triggered by the user.
We will concatenate the scenes, simulating the effect of book pages.
There are some issues, for example page transitions, up to now, we don't know if they want some 3d effect, but I could use Page Turn Curl or Page curler (Assets).

Any ideas? Is this a correct way of designing this app?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do think you don’t need to separate the scenes, If you manage page’s resources well.
It’s more flexible, and has extendability. Users would like to read pages not sequentially. they want to jump, skip and go back pages. If you just stick to scenes, I think you can’t avoid the slow turning over performances.

Comment: Hi, That's an interesting point, can you give me an idea of how can I build the pages with that approach? Because I imagine one page represents one scene. Thanks

Comment: That Question is too broad. If you use scenes, it can be simple to manage resources. If you pack resources in one scene, you can do more. But if you are a kind of noob, I recommand to use seperated scenes.(You can use rendertotexture for paging animation)

Comment: Hi! I'm a noob in unity. Let me explain what I meant.
Suppose we use the one scene approach;
I use a quad for each page, how do you manage to go from one page to the next one or previous one using just one scene? I imagine now, I have a Book game object, inside that, I have a chapter, and inside each chapter I have a page, each page contains text, audio, animations,etc.
So we are having a succession of quads? Thanks for your time!

Comment: you're right. I think you can make each pages as a prefab. And then you can load current, previous and next scenes only. unload other page resources when turning a page.

Comment: Hi! thanks, one last question and I'm done.
I place several quads, imagine we have 15 quads, Do I have to place each quad in a the same layer and order them using the sorting layer?
Suppose we have Page1 as a Game object, Page2 and so on.
Page 1 Layer = "Page Layer"
Page 1 sorting Layer = 0
Page 2 Layer = "Page Layer"
Page 2 sorting Layer = 1

how do you manage to go from one page to the next one or previous one? I mean how can you switch from one quad to the other??
I'm asking these questions because I couldn't try anything in unity till friday (I'm a linux user), my new PC is arriving  Thxs!

Comment: Unity do not have such a many layers(31 layers). It's better to put them in one layer. Put them different z. I think you need 4 different z, current page, previous page, next page and Other pages(unloaded and unseen). Each layers move z position dynamically when they perform their roles.

Answer (score 1):

this is quite a broad question but if I was approaching this I would start with the following...

Create a base class called interactive page...
An instance of an interactive page would be able to do the things you mentioned (play narration, play animations, display text, turn forward & backwards a page etc.)

I would then create another class with a list (probably called pages) which would be filled with all the customised instances of the pages I wanted to add.

I would devote a class to managing this list and the pages contained in it. If I wanted to add more books, that's when I would consider using another scene, but even then I would probably just stick to one.

There are many ways to do what you are talking about and the above is only one way off the top of my head.

Hope this helps :)